# Download SDK for Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have to run a program in VC++ and Windows 7 platform. We use Visual Studio 2008.

Where can I download the Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 and Windows 7?

Could someone provide a link to download this?

Answer (score 2):

windows 7 sdk

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Use [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en) to download the Windows 7 SDK.

Use [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21827) to download the Visual Studio 2008 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Google/Bing/Yahoo gives this when searching for "Windows 7 SDK":

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en

Here's the same thing as an .iso file for burning to a DVD:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=71deb800-c591-4f97-a900-bea146e4fae1&displaylang=en